# I'm having trouble getting a very basic command prompt text processor working. Problems with ofstream()

Tags: c++, input, command-prompt, ofstream

I've gotten my program down so far to getting the file location and file name from the user without a hitch. The problem comes from when I try to create an `ofstream` object using the file location that is provided by the user.  I basically use the `append()` function in the string library to make the location of the file to be in the standard format of `c:\users\user\my documents\"file"` which I have working.  I've tested the code without the `ofstream` object and things seem to be fine.  So I'm just unsure as to why the ofstream object won't then reference the file location specified by the string variable - filelocation.

At the moment the program should just create a file with Hello in it somewhere, **however this isn't happening and the code refuses to compile**. I have plans to get user input somewhere further down the line, but this is a small hurdle that I need to overcome before proceeding.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main() 
{
string text = "Hello" ;
string title ;
string usertitle ;
string filelocation = "C:/Users/" ;
string user ;
cout << "Input a title for your file: " ;
cin >> title ;
title.insert(title.length() , ".txt" ) ;
cout << "Your title is: " << title << endl ;
cout << endl << "Input the username associated with your computer (Caps Sensitive): " ;
cin >> user ;
filelocation.append( user ) ;
filelocation.append("/My Documents/") ;
filelocation.append(title) ;
filelocation.insert(0, "\"") ;
filelocation.insert(filelocation.length() , "\"" ) ;
cout << "Your chosen file name and location is: " << filelocation << endl ;

ofstream writer( filelocation.c_str() ) ;

if (! writer )
{
    cout << "Error opening file for output" << endl ;
    return -1 ; //Signal an error then exit the program
}
else
{
    writer << text << endl ;
    writer.close() ;
}
return 0 ;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Add a `strerror(errno)` to the "Error opening file ..." line and report what that produces in your code... [You probably need to incldue `cstdlib` or `cstring` too]

Comment: Apologies, I am completely new to this. Would you mind quoting how ow where I should include `strerror(errno)` and what it does?

Comment: Add it like this `.. << strerror(errno) << ... ` on the same line that says "Couldn't open file", and that will give you some indication of "why" it couldn't open the file.

Comment: Also I've just removed a whole bunch of stuff from the code to try and narrow down the problem. It's essentially that the ofstream() function just refuses to take a variable as an argument, is there anyway around this?

Comment: Apologies, I did not mean that the file it creates couldn't be opened, the issue is that the code just doesn't compile.

Comment: Giving what error, and what compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using minGW I think, there was like a wall of text, it's fine though the answer has been found by the guy below. It was just that the ofstream() function wasn't taking a string variable as an argument, so he found some way where it does. I don't entirely understand it, but it works :) Thanks for your input though dude.

Comment: If you have a reasonably new gcc, it should (I think) work to give it `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` to make it accept `string` as input to `fstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the argument for `std::ofstream` constructor? I think it is a `const char *`.

The constructors are declared as

```
explicit ofstream (const char* filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out);
```

So in your case, you use a `std::string` as the argument, it should be

```
   std::ofstream writer(filelocation.c_str());
```

Comment: Yeah I think that was basically the issue. The `ofstream()` function wouldn't take the string variable as an argument. Are you saying that I should write `filelocation.c_str()` as the argument for the `ofstream()` function? Apologies, I'm an absolute beginner at this.

Comment: yes. you should change your line `ofstream writer( filelocation )` to `std::ofstream writer(filelocation.c_str());`.  And if this is the answer you want, you can mark mine as the answer.

Comment: Hi again, I've changed the code like you said and it has worked a treat. The only problem now is that for some reason the file can't be created with my current iteration of the code? I've update my question and was wondering if you could spot anything that gives cause for concern. When I go to compile the program, I just get the message `Error opening file for input"` which means that something is going wrong with the ofstream object I think.

Comment: in windows, you usually use `C:\\Users\\yourname\\file_output.txt"`. And you can not use `"` as part of your file name. So you should not `insert(0, "\"");`.